# Serverless Webtask Function - Invalid verification code

Tags: serverless-framework, algolia, serverless, hugo

I'm trying to install a Serverless Webtask Function that can automatically update my Algolia index each time my static site (hugo) is updated using web hooks.

Unfortunately, I can not create a a Webtasks profile. Eveytime I try to execute ‘serverless config credentials --provider webtasks’ to create a new profile, it says ‘Invalid verification code’.

Here is my environment information: 
OS: darwin
 Node Version: 10.15. 
Serverless Version: 1.38.0

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

It's because Webtask has been official deprecated and support for it has been removed by webtask team from serverless [the pull request here](https://github.com/serverless/serverless/pull/5263).

You could try other providers such as: google cloud or aws [provider list here](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/).